# Error in the PagSeguro payment processor

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, payment-method

When filling in the information of the payment processor PagSeguro and clicking on the save button, civicrm returns the error below:

> Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/Payment/PagSeguro.php): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php
> on line 95
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'CRM/Core/Payment/PagSeguro.php'
> (include_path='/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/legacycustomsearches/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/ckeditor4/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/recaptcha/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/greenwich/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/financialacls/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/eventcart/:.:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor
> in
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php
> on line 95

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either PagSeguro extension is disabled or custom php path where the  file 'CRM/Core/Payment/PagSeguro.php' is not included under Directory settings.